# InnoDB MYSQL not supported on web server

Tags: mysql

I have created a database with `InnoDB` Engine. Now I am using [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com) and  its not supporting the `InnoDB Engine`; what should I do? My database is complete, is ready for launching!  Does any one please have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not convert it to MyISAM? Do you have FK's?

Comment: yes i have FK AND PKs how to convert it

Comment: Why not get a paid hosting? According to [this](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/000webhost.com) www.000webhost.com is not safe!

Comment: @ChristianMark, what do you mean by not safe? Not safe for what?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. The provider I was forced to use only had MyISAM and I developed in InnoDB.
It possible to migrate since it seems MyISAM is ignoring all the FK commands you use when creatg the schema.

I used a simple export from Mysql workbench and imported schema and content in the remote host.

I think the constrains of the database would be kept since I developed and tested using InnoDB with FK checking. If your code is solid the risk should be minimal that the database loses integrity. 
But there can of course be cases of unforseen problems with the keys if you don´t manage some constrains in your code.

An overview of the [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) and [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) storage engines could give you the answer if you have relied on anything else that sets the two apart.

Comment: InnoDB is vastly different to MyISAM, even if it doesn't seem so. It's not "just" FKs, there's much, much more to it.

Comment: Sure there are more to it. But I would be surprised if a solution for InnoDB would not function on MyISAM. The thing most people would notice is the lack of FK checking and the speed difference in SEELECT statements. But to give a very definitive answer to this question the we need to see the schema and the queries for the database in question.

Comment: @Einar - you could also run into serious trouble if your application uses transactions and you are counting on rollbacks to clean up unfinished operations after an error for example.